# How to open a excel-file directly in Chrome instead of download, and save it back up to..?

Tags: excel, google-chrome, sharepoint

I know this is a quite delicate question since Chrome for some reason always want to download a file before viewing it.

Is it correct that Chrome cant 'only open' a file? How to work around that? It wont help me to use the "always open this file.." (i think) because the real problem I have is when Im done with the file i want to save/submit back to the instance on the server and that information is gone..

So an exemple..

Im in an SharePoint (native) enviroment and click a (excel-)report from a list I want to do some kind of change in. The file opens as supposed to whatever browser Im on. But when Im done with my changes I want to save/submit the form/report back to the server..! If im on IE or Edge Ill just press save and Excel knows where to send my stuff. If im on Chrome, then Excel tries to save the file to my 'downloads' and I get a error message saying that the submit was unsuccessful.

What to do? Any suggestions?

Comment: What does this have to do with Reporting Services?

Comment: Oh, sorry @Brian.. nothing really. We use reporting services in the same module but in this matter, no connection. My bad.